# Ubuntu NumPy up-to-date but pip3 list showed older version

Tags: numpy, ubuntu

I want to upgrade my NumPy with `sudo pip3 install numpy --upgrade` in my Ubuntu 20.04. However, while it showed `Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (1.23.4)`, in `pip3 list`, it showed that NumPy version is 1.18.5, which is an older version.

Comment: Try `pip3 install numpy --upgrade` (without sudo), I tried upgrading a package in mine with sudo and it show different version until I rerun it without sudo.

Comment: @Martheen it works, never thought sudo will be the problem, thanks.

Comment: [Avoid `sudo pip` as much as possible](https://askubuntu.com/q/802544/301745)